# App Installer stopped displaying German UI for my sideloaded German UWP App

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, appinstaller

**EDIT EDIT:** This problem was no longer reproducible after Microsoft rolled out a newer version of App Installer.

EDIT: App Installer doesn't provide a German UI for my sideloaded UWP package. The default language is configured as German (de-DE) and the bilingual app (German and English) has a German UI for German users. What can I configure to fix the App Installer?

Recently, the App Installer stopped providing a German UI when a German user installs the app package. Due to my development process, I can switch out the current online package with any previous version. (Docker can be a blessing.) Now, when these older versions are installed, App Installer now only provides a English UI, where screenshots prove it had previously been German a month ago (on the 17.09.2021).

Nothing I have tried since then has given me any indication I have any influence over the language selection in the App Installer.

Is there any documentation as to the chosen display language/localization in App Installer? Have I overseen anything? Or is there a bug in App Installer?

Other info:

- App Installer version 1.16.12653.0
- Visual Studio 2019 CE version 16.11.5.

SIDE NOTE: I've been dockerizing the published app packages (the contents of `./AppPackages` after packaging the project for side-loading as described https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-using-the-packaging-wizard). As a result, I have a docker image for each version of an nginx server that serves just the files from that version. To roll out a out a newer version, I swap out the docker image. This has proven successful, as the testers have been successfully installing and upgrading with the link.

Comment: What if the app is not installed in the docker image? Will it give the same behavior?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify, that the app is not installed inside any docker images. It is a requirement of the side-loading configuration & process that the files are reachable relative to a given URL. The docker image is merely the web server to host the installer files.

Comment: So the sideloaded app still shows the German UI correctly, right? The issue is that the App Installer doesn't provide a German UI, am I correct?

Comment: Correct. The app supports both English and German, and German (de-DE) is the configured default language.